# Animate Div to Reveal Div Behind It

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

EDIT: It was pointed out that I had a syntax error in my original jsFiddle code - it's fixed. That was unintentional and not my question. My question was instead of doing what I do now, how can I animate it so there's a slide animation? Thanks, sorry for the confusion!

I'm trying to build out a quiz where you click on a radio button and a sliding animation occurs that reveals the next question. I tried using .slideToggle but that wasn't working, or at least I could get it to work.

Any ideas? I was trying to stick to regular ole' jQuery instead of UI to save performance.

[Here's a jsFiddle of what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkH8n/377/). Right now I currently add a class that adds a higher z-index to a div behind another. But I'd like a sliding animation instead.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<form id="question1" class="panel">
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="1">1
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="2">2
</form>
<form id="question2" class="panel">
    <input type="radio" name="test2" value="3">3
    <input type="radio" name="test2" value="4">4
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#question1, #question2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#question1 {
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: blue;
}

#question2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.z-index20 {
    z-index: 20
}
```

JS

```
$('#question1 input').on('change', function() {
    var $questionAnswer1 = $('input[name=test1]:checked', '#question1').val();    
    $("#question2").addClass("z-index20");

    $('#question2 input').on('change', function() {
        var $questionAnswer2 = $('input[name=test2]:checked', '#question2').val(); 
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/ZkH8n/373/

Comment: I'm looking to animate my reveal using a sliding motion. The jsFiddle error was a mistake on my end, not my original problem. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size, we basically just add a transition to the left setting of each question, then move it off canvas.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ZkH8n/383/))

```
var handleChange = function (e) {
    e.target.parentNode.style.transition = 'left 1s ease-in-out';
    e.target.parentNode.style.left = '100%';
}
var options = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="question"] input');
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);
}
```

The same script with jQuery

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ZkH8n/382/))

```
var handleChange = function(e) {
    $(e.target.parentNode).css('transition', 'left 1s ease-in-out');
    $(e.target.parentNode).css('left', '100%');
}
$('[id*="question"] input').on('change',handleChange);
```

Comment: This is exactly the animation I was looking for! I'm going to add a few more questions to the pot. Any chance you know how to do this in jQuery as the code will get mighty confusing on the tenth question? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why wouldn't you recommend it? It's usually my default because of easier syntax and cross-browser support.

Comment: Just saw your change - exactly what I was looking for, thanks! However, it starts off on the second div, not first. I'll see if I can fix it.

Reading through your solution quickly, I don't see anything that would affect (reasonably) old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

## Sliding

I would recommend sliding the layer *off* instead of the second layer *on*. jQuery also has a *very* simple and easy way to do this using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
 $('#question1').animate({
    'left': '-510px' // 500 is width of container plus 10px for default margin
}, 200); // Adjust 200
```

You can add a call back function too:

```
$('#question1').animate({
    'left': '-510px' // 500 is width of container plus 10px for default margin
}, 200, function () { // Adjust 200
    var questionAnswer = $(this).find('input[name=test2]:checked');
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/ZkH8n/379/)

---

#### Syntax Error

In your code, your main error is here:

```
$('#question2 input').on('change', function() {
    var $questionAnswer2 = $('input[name=test2]:checked', '#question2').val();
```

You need to close this to result in:

```
$('#question2 input').on('change', function() {
    var $questionAnswer2 = $('input[name=test2]:checked', '#question2').val(); 
});
```

---

Small syntax errors such as this can be very troubling *(I've noticed almost 400 revisions)*, luckily you can use sites such as **[JSHint](http://jshint.com)** or a more comprehensive **[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com)**. This is also integrated in JSFiddle.

[image: Button]

---

## [Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/ZkH8n/374/)

Answer (score -1):

Your js has syntax errors, so it isn't even running.

Just fix that and you should be good. (Forgot to close first function)
Your broken indentation makes it very confusing.

Comment: I did not down vote you, however, it wasn't the solution I was looking for. The jsFiddle syntax error was just a mistake, not my problem. My problem was trying to animate that transition from one div to the next using a sliding animation. Currently, the "animation" effect is based on adding a class. But that's rather boring. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: "I tried using .slideToggle but that wasn't working, or at least I could get it to work." It works fine without the syntax errors.